# kendo mvc grid ondatabound find total number of row that match a specific criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

May i know how to find the total number of records that have a column match to a specific criteria?

//Example

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock).Title("Units In Stock");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
        .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
     )
)


<script>
   function onDataBound(arg) {

   **How can i find the total number of records that the Unit Price equal to 10?**

    }
</script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the items with $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItems(). Once you have them you just need to iterate through them and add matching results to a counter.

```
function onDataBound(arg) {
    var count = 0;
    $($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItems()).each(function (index, item) {
    if (this.UnitPrice== 10)
        count++;
    });
}
```